# Cheap embedded WCFclient

Tags: wcf, embedded, windows-ce, embedded-linux, .net-micro-framework

I have been tasked to find a development board with the following requirements:

1. The embedded system is supposed to connect to between 1-8 [minimum 1 LCD monitor maximum 8 LCD monitor but keep it one for the simplicity at this stage]
2. The data(a JPEG or GIF at this stage but could be a webpage in future) to be shown on the screen is coming from a WCF service running on an external IP address from internet. The choice of Binding on WCF service can be your choice. BasicHttpBinding for instance(security is not an issue at this stage). Bandwidth is not an issue at all. WCF setup on the server is highly flexible which means our service could be SOAP based or REST based or whatever which is more reasonable.

Should we go for an embedded Linux board or Windows CE board? The reason for this question is cost factor as Microsoft boards are more expensive than Linux boards.
What would be the cheapest board which I could potentially find to consume a WCF service. Cost is a deciding factor in this project. What are our options? Are there any projects out there doing something similar?

Comment: In considering a linux solution, the first thing you would want to do would be to develop a test program capable of consuming your service when running on a desktop linux machine, to get an idea if that is plausible, and what it would require.  Then you can go shopping for embedded platforms.  With your multiple monitor issue, you might want to consider if it would be simpler to have one processor per monitor - possibly even using android tablets (or fire-sale Surface tablets?).  Or you could see if you could get a good deal on USB connected monitors or USB-VGA adapters.

Answer (score 2):

"Microsoft boards are cheaper than Linux boards."  What does that mean?  Microsoft (nor Linux) make boards.  Many boards support both OSes.  Windows CE runs as low as $3 for the runtime, which is also pretty cheap as far as BOM cost.  Your NRE cost is going to be in development, and I'd say if you're a Linux house go Linux, if you're a Windows house, go CE.

CE is going to consume WCF with you writing way less code, though Mono might bring some parity is you're on Linux in that regard.

Beyond that, it's hard to make judgement on hardware for you.  We don't know your processing requirements, or really even any hardware interface requirements.  You say you need "one LCD".  How so?  LVDS?  HDMI? VGA? Proprietary cable?  All of those options are out there.  It could be that the display you pick costs more than the board so a cheap board that requires an expensive display doesn't really help you if overall cost is an issue.

Comment: Thank you ctacke for the response. In regards to processing requirements the board should periodically[must be configurable] query a WCF service and then display a mixture of text and pictures.Something like s slideshow.

Comment: In regards to displaying we want to go for the cheapest display as well. the resolution is 1280*1024. LVDS + LCD. There are no proprietary cable. Cost of the displays are quite important as well therefore I appreciate your comments on displaying alternatives.

Comment: @user1901646 LVDS will not be the cheapest solution. I think that a simple RGB interface would be cheaper. Touch screen required? Beside that, there are still many questions, so 'ctacke' gave you some overview what you should do first to get them answered.